# How to Set port in next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, port, next.js

One application is running on port 3000 and I want to run another application on a different port from the default port, which is 3000. How do I change this in React Next.js? My `package.json` currently contains:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
},
```

And the CLI command that I use to start dev is `npm run dev`.

Comment: https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/102

Comment: `next dev` will automatically use another port if port 3000 is in use.

Answer (score 486, accepted):

This work for me:

```
"scripts": { 
    "dev": "next dev -p 8080",
    "start": "next start -p 8080",
},
```

Comment: It didn't wokrd out.

Comment: If you're using the `dev` next command in your script, for me today this only works by specifying after next command, e.g. `next dev -p 8080` and `next start -p 8080` for prod mode, as opposed to before like this: `next -p 8080 dev`.

Comment: This works for me in project that created by create-next-app. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Run `npm run dev -p 5000` to run the app on port 5000

Comment: @C10N With that, I got `Invalid project directory provided, no such directory`. I used `npm run dev -- -p 5000` instead and that worked.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work anymore for `start` (next 13.5.6). But this works: `PORT=3001 npm run start` (from the command line), or just changing the "scripts" part of `package.json`to `"start": "PORT=3001 next start"`

Answer (score 79):

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev -p 8080", // for dev 
    "start": "next start -p 8080" // for prod
},
```

Comment: This really isn't; the port shouldn't be baked into a startup script.

Answer (score 43):

With `yarn`, `pnpm` you can easily pass any arguments:
`yarn dev -p 8080` or `yarn dev --port=8080`

With `npm` using `--` to pass arguments:
`npm run dev -- -p 8080`

Comment: It was the most practical answer for me. thanks

Answer (score 33):

The application will start at http://localhost:3000 by default. The default port can be changed with -p, like so:

```
 npx next dev -p 4000
```

Or using the PORT environment variable:

```
PORT=4000 npx next dev
```

#note that I used npx not npm

You can also set the hostname to be different from the default of 0.0.0.0, this can be useful for making the application available for other devices on the network. The default hostname can be changed with -H, like so:

```
 npx next dev -H 192.168.1.2
```

If you're getting an error that the port is already in use, what you can do to resolve it on windows is

```
Go to the Task Manager.

Scroll and find a task process named. Node.js: Server-side

End this particular task.
```

Answer (score 26):

just need to do:

```
yarn dev -p PORT_YOU_LIKE
```

Comment: For long term value, please explain why this code solves OP's issue. Code only answers are frowned upon. Explanations help future visitors learn, and apply this knowledge to similar issues that have in their own code. They are also more likely to be upvoted. Consider editing to improve your answer, and keep quality of SO Answers high. Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: the .env file doesn't work on next js. Anyone who has a working solution can help drop the solution

Comment: I like this approach. This worked for me instead of changing PORT in any other file. Thank you.

Comment: In my case the port parameter `yarn dev -p 4000` was just ignored. App still responded on `http://localhost:3000/` not on `http://localhost:4000/` (although I could see in the terminal `concurrently "npm run server" "npm run client" -port 4000`).

Answer (score 18):

## A workaround using environment variables via .env file

Thanks to this [github comment](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/11408#issuecomment-617034254)

**For development**

1. Create a script for your dev environment in the project root e.g. `dev-server.js`

```
// dev-server.js
require('dotenv').config(); // require dotenv
const cli = require('next/dist/cli/next-dev');

cli.nextDev(['-p', process.env.PORT || 3000]);
```

2. Then you can set a custom port in your `.env` like this: `PORT=3002`
3. Update the dev command in your `package.json` to use the `dev-server.js` script like this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node dev-server.js"
  }
```

4. Run `npm run dev` and the NextJS application will start on port 3002.

**For production**

1. Create a script for your prod environment in the project root e.g. `prod-server.js`

```
// prod-server.js
require('dotenv').config(); // require dotenv
const cli = require('next/dist/cli/next-start');

cli.nextStart(['-p', process.env.PORT || 3000]);
```

2. Then you can set a custom port in your `.env` like this: `PORT=3002`
3. Update the start command in your `package.json` to use the `prod-server.js` script like this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "node prod-server.js"
  }
```

4. Run `npm run start` and the NextJS application will start on port 3002. (Don't forget to build the project before with `npm run build`)

[dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) should be installed via `npm install dotenv`, required and configured in the scripts as seen in the code snippets before.

Note from the [github comment](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/11408#issuecomment-617034254):

> There are some hosting providers that just force us to have server.js/index.js file. The bonus of the above solution is that it doesn't require any additional dependency.

Answer (score 14):

There are two ways to do so:

In your `package.json` file, add `-p 8080` to the dev/start scripts to start the server on port 8080:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next -p 8080",
    "build": "next build",
    "profile-build": "next build --profile",
    "start": "next start -p 8080"
  }
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to hardcode this in the `package.json` file, you could start the script with ENV variable PORT.

```
PORT=8080 npm run dev
```

Visit [vercel documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/cli#development) for more information.

Comment: Nice. So curious why this is the only answer (here and elsewhere that I've seen) that mentions using the `PORT=` variable. There's no reason a port number should be baked into an `npm` script.

Comment: `'PORT' is not recognized as an internal or external command` i am facing this

Answer (score 6):

Usually, the port is environment specific so it shouldn't go to git repository. Thus the best practise is to define it in `.env.local`, and it can be read from there using the following start script:

```json
// package.json
"scripts": {
  "start": "[ -e .env.local ] && set -a && . ./.env.local; next start",
},
```

Using the `set -a` will export the sourced environment variables, and the Next.JS start script will use the `PORT` environment variable if defined. Note that this script won't work in Windows.

Comment: Works great for me! The command looks cryptic if you don't know shell scripting, but I prefer this over the alternatives. Thank you!

Comment: Could you explain the elements of the command?

Answer (score 5):

Setting port number in npm script is not good idea at all.

From terminal you can pass the port number by using following command

```
SET PORT=3001 && npm start
```

Comment: I am currently testing 2 applications on the same PC, for that having one single PORT variable won't work (because both applications would use the same variable). How can we introduce different port varialbles (like APP1_PORT and APP2_PORT) ?

Answer (score 1):

For NextJS 13, all you have to do is specify it in your terminal. Run:

```
npm run dev -p 4000
```

To run the app on port 4000

Answer (score 1):

Using the `-p` or `--port` option with the `next dev` command allows you to specify a custom port for your Next.js development server.

For example:

```bash
next dev -p 4000
```

This command will start your Next.js development server on port 4000.

Answer (score 0):

following example will be work for nextjs and pm2 combination
pm2 start npx --name "next" -- next -p 3001

Answer (score 0):

Another way is using a custom Server file in Next.js

So you can just set your port in env file and not having to change anywhere else.

Somehting like below example

```
const express = require('express');
const next = require('next');
const getConfig = require('../next.config');


const { basePath, port } = getConfig.publicRuntimeConfig;

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({ dev });

app.prepare().then(() => {
  const app = express();

  app.use(express.json());
  app.use(express.urlencoded({ limit: '20kb', extended: false }));


  app.listen(3000, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('server running on port: ' + 3000);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/69780065/6831932 doesn't work for me, but fails with

```
/path/to/project/node_modules/next/dist/bin/next:147
commands[command]().then((exec)=>exec(forwardedArgs)
                                 ^

TypeError: exec is not a function
    at /path/to/project/node_modules/next/dist/bin/next:147:34
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

Node.js v19.8.1
npm ERR! Lifecycle script `dev` failed with error:
npm ERR! Error: command failed
npm ERR!   in workspace: frontend@1.0.0
npm ERR!   at location: /path/to/project/apps/frontend
```

My workaround is to use `node:child_process` to spawn next:

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
// For some reason trying to invoke nextDev() from 'next/dist/cli/next-dev'
// doesn't work, even though others report success with it.
// So, let's try invoking `next` as a child process...
const {spawn} = require('node:child_process');

// I have a monorepo with node_modules and .env only at project root.
// If you don't, you can remove the '/../../' part.
const projectRoot = process.cwd() + '/../../';

// Get the .env file from the root of the project.
dotenv.config({path: projectRoot + '.env'});

// Get next binary path and default args.
const nextPath = projectRoot + 'node_modules/.bin/next';
const FRONTEND_PORT = process.env.FRONTEND_PORT || '4000';
const FRONTEND_HOST = process.env.FRONTEND_HOST || 'localhost';
const nextArgs = [
  'dev',
  '-p', FRONTEND_PORT,
  '-H', FRONTEND_HOST,
];

// Spawn next process.
const next = spawn(nextPath, nextArgs);

// Log output from next process.
next.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  if (typeof data === 'string') {
    console.log(data);
  } else {
    console.log(data.toString());
  }
});

// Log errors from next process.
next.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  if (typeof data === 'string') {
    console.error(data);
  } else {
    console.error(data.toString());
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. 

You can start your app with this command:

```
npx env-cmd -f ".env" npm run dev
```

Where `env-cmd -f ".env"` loads environment variables.
And `.env` file looks as below:

```
PORT=4000 # new port
```

2. 

You could also simplify this process by modify package.json `scripts`:

```
"dev": "npx env-cmd -f \".env\" next dev"
```

And after that:

```
npm run dev
```

Answer (score -3):

Apart from hard coding it in `package.json`, you could do it via `.env` file:

```
PORT=4000
```