# I am not able to run the next js app below port 1023 shows the error below is the details

Tags: next.js

I have updated the script then run sudo npm run dev it gives error

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev -p 80",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  }
```

below (the error)

```
Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 0.0.0.0:80
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1313:21)
    at listenInCluster (node:net:1378:12)
    at Server.listen (node:net:1465:7)
    at /home/mohd/Desktop/news/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/start-server.js:29:13
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.start [as default] (/home/mohd/Desktop/news/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/start-server.js:24:11)
    at nextDev (/home/mohd/Desktop/news/node_modules/next/dist/cli/next-dev.js:115:30)
    at /home/mohd/Desktop/news/node_modules/next/dist/bin/next:119:34 {
  code: 'EACCES',
  errno: -13,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '0.0.0.0',
  port: 80
}
```

I have tried various solution [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60147499/how-to-set-port-in-next-js?rq=1)

Comment: Usually ports below 1024 are 'privileged' meaning you have to be root/admin to open them.

Comment: Ya, I know this but I am using sudo to run the next app how can I run below port 1023?

Comment: setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' /path/to/nodejs this works thanks ...