# How to get the -p argument value in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, next.js

If my **Nexs.js** app is started with

```
yarn dev
```

Where `package.json` defines it as

```
{
   "scripts": {
     "dev": "next dev -p 4000"
   }
}
```

How I get this `4000` value from the `-p` switch?

Because `process.env.PORT` is not set this way.

```
const getBaseUrl = () => {
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') return '';  // browser use relative path

  // How to replace the ???? with the value of -p, defaulting to 3000 if not set

  return 'http://localhost:????';  // dev SSR should use localhost
}
```

Comment: What is your `yarn dev` script?

Comment: It's Next.js....

Comment: So we're *assuming* it is `next dev`? Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60147499/how-to-set-port-in-next-js), it seems like it should be possible to do `yarn dev -p ...`, but if it doesn't, you could always change your script to `next dev -p ...`.

Comment: @caTS you are so pedantic!!

Comment: @cant you just change the port in your json script to 3000 ? or there is somthing else using that port?

Comment: if you need to set the .json port using a .env file this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34650527/how-to-use-environment-variables-in-package-json) might help you