# Why NextJS web server listens extra TCP ports?

Tags: node.js, next.js

If i create simple NextJS project with npx create-next-app@latest and run it with "npm run dev" (or build it with "npm run build" and then run it with "npm start") - I will see in Process Explorer - SysInternals there are several node.exe processes.
One of them listens 3000 Tcp port: [image]
and other one listens 2 random ports: [image] The command line of the second one is
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" X:\test\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\jest-worker/processChild.js [image]
Why NextJS listens these extra ports?
Can i configure them to be fixed (not random) ?

I have hosting with blocked listening ports. I can open some - but i don't know how to configure it to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

### **Another solution to the collection of answers :3**

---

**These are child process' / subprocess' by node:** *"X:\test\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\jest-worker/processChild.js"*

> *npm start -p [port]*
>
> **This post explains how to set the port:** [How to Set port in next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60147499/how-to-set-port-in-next-js)

---

You can also see the ports are incrementing, that means that the previous port is still active, and it then opens a new port that is just one higher that the other 50727 -> 50728.

The TCPV6 is just the 128bits version of TCPV4 / 32bits (it defaults to TCP). So overlook (in this case) it if it's a duplicate of an already existing/open port.

I'm pretty sure this is the reason.

Hope this helps anyway, and have a wonderful day :3

Comment: Are these ports of child processes are configurable ?

Comment: My app listens on 3000. And its ok. But also NEXTJS try to listen on 50727, 50728 (random port numbers). Are these ports of child processes are configurable ?

Comment: @Denis Ah sorry for the late reply, I'm currently moving so the weeks are a bit busy haha. Anyway, I'm not entirely sure if you can set them to other ports (redirect / portforward) them, I haven't done it before myself so yeah. I'm pretty sure that you can only decide where the ports are assigned too, is if you create the child processes yourself.